# Storing part of a text file into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have program that reads this text file:

> N
>
> How many parameters does a copy constructor accept?
>
> 1
>
> S
>
> What standard Java class do all classes inherit from?
>
> Object
>
> m
>
> What is "computer".substring(3, 5)?
>
> - mpute
>
> + pu
>
> - put
>
> N
>
> What is the value of pi?
>
> 3.141592653

And needs to store only these lines (start with + or -) into the array list:

**- mpute**

**+ pu**

**- put**

So far I have this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Quiz {

public static void test() {
    ArrayList<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What quiz are you taking? ");
    String name = input.next();
    File file = new File(name);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(name);

    while (s.hasNext()) {
        choices.add(s.next());
    }

}

}
```

How will I store only those lines into the array list instead of all the lines?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you format your question better, because there are a lot of gibberish unrelated to the question but let me answer the question in the subject.

A simple way to do this is to use this

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/YourFile.txt"));
```

This will put all of lines in your file and you can take it from there.